# getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated counterparts for files that are not mime types

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to development and I faced such a problem, I need to find the file in the downloads folder, since getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated I read that now it is better to use instead:

```
1. Context # getExternalFilesDir (String)
2. MediaStore
3. Intent # ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
```

I tried using the first method to get a list of all documents in the Downloads folder

```
File file = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
                File[] files = file.listFiles();
                int length = files.length;
```

but length is always 0, although there are files in this folder.

I also cannot use the second method because MediaStore uses a mime type, but my file is not a mime type, since its extension is .gpx
Maybe someone can tell me how to solve this problem

File downloading:

```
private void mapOptions()
    {
        bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(mContext);
        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.bootom_map_menu);

        LinearLayout open = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.open_map_bottom_menu);
        LinearLayout download = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.download_map_bottom_menu);


        open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });


        download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                

                
                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);


                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(mapUri);
                request.setDescription("Downloading...");
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);

                String strPath = mapUri.getPath().toString();


                File file = new File(strPath);
                filename = file.getName() + ".gpx";



                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
                request.setRequiresCharging(false);
                request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
                request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);





                downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

                bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();


            }
        });


        bottomSheetDialog.show();
    }
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            long id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
            if (downloadID == id) {
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Uri uri = dm.getUriForDownloadedFile(downloadID);
                
                
                Log.i("Uri result", "Uri to file:" + uri.getPath().toString());
                
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: getExternalFilesDir is no replacement for getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(). Different paths. Only the last one can be used for the public Download folder. Use it. Try it. Test it. It does not harm.

Comment: I dont think that mimetype is a problem for mediastore.  Did you try mediastore? Please do. Post your code.

Comment: `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` does not find files but lets the user select a file. From anywhere.

Comment: I can assure you that gpx files are also indexed by media store scanner.

Comment: `need to find the file in the downloads folder, s` The file? One file? Which file? How did that file land in that folder! Who did it? Which app? Or how?

Comment: @blackapps I have an application in which a user can load a map in gpx format, and other users can download or open it, I found a gpx parser that will help me transfer to points from this file, to a map, but in order to use this file in gpx parser, it must be downloaded on the phone and I need to get a route to it. I found a way to get the route to this file, but when I get the route, it is returned to me in this format / all_downloads / 5393 and this is the whole problem, that at the end of this route, not the name of the file, but its id is written

Comment: Dont call it a route if you mean a file system path. You took the last part of a content scheme and used it as path for File class that will not go.

Comment: You did not tell who downloaded the file and how. And then you did not tell how you obtained that false path. Please post your code if relevant.

Comment: @blackapps I've added my code

Comment: `Log.i("Uri result", "Uri to file:" + uri.getPath().toString());` That makes no sense. Better: `Log.i("Uri result", "Uri toString(): " + uri.toString());`

Comment: Now look if your gpx parser can also read from your nice uri directly. If it is maintained it should be able. Otherwise ask the developer to add that possibility. You can also add it yourself. Only a few lines of code extra.

Comment: `filename = file.getName() + ".gpx";` Please tell which filename you finally get.

Comment: @blackapps Also another question, I tried to convert the Uri data to a file but as soon as I used file.exists the result was false. Maybe you can tell why this is so?

Comment: `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);` But then you know exactly the path for your file and you can use it for the parser. It will be: `String path = new File(getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename).getAbsolutePath();`

Comment: @blackapps map_034.gpx I've added ".gpx" because I use the firebase database and it also does not recognize gpx files because of this, when a user downloads a file, it jumps without an extension and the user just gets a file map_034

Comment: `I tried to convert the Uri data to a file ` I already told you that what you did did not make sense. Uri.getPath() is useless.

Comment: @blackapps ok, I uderstand. but won't it be a problem that the getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() is deprecated. it seems to me that this is not a good practice to use deprecated functions

Comment: Deprecated yes. But it works on Android 11 and even in Android 12 at the moment. If you dont want then use the uri and adapt the parser. Its little work. Or write your own parser. Its pretty simple a .gpx file.